# Simple PHP issue, I'm sure

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

I just set up a new Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit server, picking whatever package for Apache it came with.  I'm trying to open this index.html file in my browser:

```
<html><body><h1>Testing Database</h1>

<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","****","****");
if(!$con) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("Test", $con);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM main");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['name'];
   echo "<br />";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>

</body></html>
```

I had created a database and table in MySQL.  I made a phpinfo.php file (containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`) that ran just fine.  But for some reason, Internet Explorer only shows the title [Testing Database], and Chrome shows just the title, plus:

```
"; } mysql_close($con); ?>
```

I'm following a tutorial here, is there something wrong with my setup?  I feel like I'm missing some sort of parenthesis in this tiny chunk of code, but cannot find it.

Comment: Is your server set up to interpret `.html` file extensions as PHP files? Try changing the extension to `.php`?

Comment: Clear your browser caches and try again.

Comment: @TheZ — The question says the file is called phpinfo.php.

Comment: @vee I actually did that, but I guess stackoverflow.com parsed it out?  weird.  anyway, it ran fine

Comment: @Quentin No, actually it says that file ran fine. Above the first code block it says this file is called `index.html`

Comment: rename `index.html` to `index.php`. Fix syntax errors in your file.

Comment: What do you mean by "I made a phpinfo.php file (containing ) that ran just fine." ?? What was on phpinfo.php? What's the WHOLE name and extension of the file whose code you show in the question?

Comment: @armani: next time, choose "View source" in your web browser, and you will immediately notice that all your PHP code is displayed: that means nothing gets executed in your file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

index.html?

`.html` pages won't parse as PHP, you need to have the `.php` extention, or use some htaccess to force it through the PHP parser.

Other than that, there was a syntax error in your file, change to:

```
<html><body><h1>Testing Database</h1>

<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","****","****");
if(!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("Test", $con);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM main");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['name'];
   echo "<br />";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>

</body></html>
```

notice the removal of the `{` from this line:

```
if(!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: OP can also modify httpd.conf to process .html pages with php tags

Comment: No worries, I'm sure most developers made silly mistakes like this while learning too...I know I did!

Comment: @Matt: I'm on a test server, and would rather my code be as portable as possible without modifying configs if I can.  But good to know!

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if(!$con) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
```

has a closing '}' missing

Comment: If that were the problem, there'd be a massive Parse Error, or nothing at all.

Comment: Fixed that, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Right. That WILL BE the problem when PHP works on OP's server. Anyhow, the fact he says "I made a phpinfo.php file (containing ) that ran just fine." is misleading.

Comment: @armani - it's not you downvoting this (and MiDo's) I hope? They are correct, even if they are not the answer you're after.

Comment: Yes, there was a syntax error in the code, but the primary error was that the server was not configured to execute PHP in .html files.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `}` at the end of following line:

```
if(!$con) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
```

Comment: If that were the problem, there'd be a massive Parse Error, or nothing at all.

Comment: @Kolink But the fact still remains that there *is* a closing brace missing on that line. I can only hope that that was an error in copying.

Answer (score -1):

You do not have PHP installed, or you don't have a server that calls PHP.

The reason you see what you are seeing is because everything from `<?php` through to `<br />` is being seen as one big invalid HTML tag.

Comment: OP mentioned that phpinfo.php ran fine.

Comment: If PHP were "running fine", why is it not being parsed?

Comment: The sentence says "or you don't have a server that calls PHP". That explains why PHP source code is visible in the browser.

Comment: Who said his php block wasn't being parsed?

Comment: @Kolink because `.html` files do not parsed as PHP script

Comment: @Alexander: Wrong. You can set up your web server to parse PHP code inside .htm .html and .jpg files (or any other extension you choose) if you want.

Comment: @Jocelyn I think Alexander meant "without hax".

Comment: @Jocelyn just because you can do that, it doesn't mean that this was done by OP.

Comment: @Alexander (and Matt): OK with you. I thought you meant "in general".